# Ejabberd Packet parsing using erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Ejabberd server receives packet like this:

```
  {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user1@localhost/resource">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user2@localhost">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"id">>,<<"947yW-9">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<">">>},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Helllo wassup!">>}]}]}
```

I want to fetch data from this packet.
Needed data : Type, If the body has a certain parameter, say `{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>}`
I am doing the following operations:

```
  {_XMLEL, TYPE, DETAILS , _BODY} = Packet
```

This provides me the type : `<<"message">>` or `<<"iq">>` or `<<"presence">>`.

To check if DETAILS has `{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>}` I do this:

```
 Has_Attribute=lists:member({<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},DETAILS)
```

Is there any better way to do this?
I also need the `to` and `from` attributes from the packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of pattern matching in the function head together with a fold over the details to extract everything you need.

The function below returns a list of key-value tuples, where the `<<"type">>` tuple is artificially created so the list is homogenous:

```
extract({xmlel, Type, Details, _}) ->
    [{<<"type">>,Type} |
     lists:foldl(fun(Key, Acc) ->
                         case lists:keyfind(Key, 1, Details) of
                             false -> Acc;
                             Pair -> [Pair|Acc]
                         end
                 end, [], [<<"from">>,<<"to">>,<<"xml:lang">>])];
extract(_) -> [].
```

The first clause matches the `{xmlel, ...}` tuple, extracting `Type` and `Details`. The return value consists of a list with head `{<<"type">>,Type}` followed by a tail formed from folding over the list of keys to be extracted from `Details`. The second clause matches anything not a `{xmlel, ...}` tuple and just returns the empty list.

Putting this function into a module named `z` and passing it your data:

```
1> z:extract({xzlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user1@localhost/resource">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user2@localhost">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"id">>,<<"947yW-9">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<">">>},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Helllo wassup!">>}]}]}).
[{<<"type">>,<<"message">>},
 {<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},
 {<<"to">>,<<"user2@localhost">>},
 {<<"from">>,<<"user1@localhost/resource">>}]
```